# How To Get Specific Data From A Text Box in VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, textbox, innertext

I have grabbed the text from a webpage, and put it into a TextBox using:

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
```

Now in that text box, I have :

Show Me HowDevice Status
ORDER CARTRIDGE LESS THAN 700 PAGES
Help
Pause/Resume     Continue

I want to be able to grab the "ORDER CARTRIDGE LESS THAN 700 PAGES" from the textbox, and put it as the text to TextBox2.Text 
I have been looking for ways to do this, but I'm just not finding any resolution.  This is the simplest amount of text I can get the page down to.  This text can also change depending on the printer's status.  So I'm basically looking for a way to get the data between Status and Help, and assign it to another textbox's text.  I hope this makes sense...  If it's easier to get it from the HTML please assist me with that.  Below is some of the code from the HTML of the page.

```
<div  id="Text1"  style="font-size:14px; padding-top: .7em; padding-bottom: .7em;" >ORDER CARTRIDGE
LESS THAN 700 PAGES
</div>
```

Comment: Look at this [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets1p14.html). Is this what you want?

Comment: No it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: You should be able to easily using the String methods or RegEx to extract the value between those two words--there are many examples on here of how to do that.  However, that's not at all a good way to do that.  It would be far better to use HtmlAgilityPack to get the value of the specific HTML node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

If you have a good reason to display the whole text in textbox1, and the string you require is always the second line:

```
TextBox2.Text = Textbox1.Lines(1)
```

To get direct from the browser:

```
TextBox2.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Text1").InnerText
```

But as the others have mentioned, there are probably better ways to accomplish your task.
What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Well it will work fine if the webbrowser has a page loaded that contains the html in your question. Are you sure it has the page loaded when you run my code? If yes, are you sure the html is as you put it in your question. a NullReferenceException sounds like it could not find an element with the id "Text1"

Comment: LOL.  Did not realize how long it took for that page to load.  Man..  I have been looking for this ALL DAY!  I really appreciate your help!